# Failure with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, formatting

I've got a pipes jSON feed @ http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=32188be96d1caf97c46a6fcfd8c00820&_render=json

```
{
"count":4,
"value":{
  "title":"Copy of Twitter Farm #talkdesign Pipe",
  "description":"Pipes Output",
  "link":"http:\/\/pipes.yahoo.com\/pipes\/pipe.info?_id=32188be96d1caf97c46a6fcfd8c00820",
  "pubDate":"Sat, 29 Oct 2011 05:40:41 -0700",
  "generator":"http:\/\/pipes.yahoo.com\/pipes\/",
  "callback":"",
  "items":[
     {
        "link":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/talk_design\/statuses\/130251640623214592",
        "description":"talk_design: Pretty cool interactive music video for Ellie Goulding's Lights! <a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http:\/\/search.twitter.com\/search?q=%23webgl\" title=\"#webgl\" class=\" \">#webgl<\/a> <a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http:\/\/t.co\/kkA3ON09\">http:\/\/t.co\/kkA3ON09<\/a>",
        "pubDate":"Sat, 29 Oct 2011 11:56:25 +0000",
        "guid":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/talk_design\/statuses\/130251640623214592",
        "author":"talk_design@twitter.com (Talk.Design)",
        "media:content":{
           "height":"48",
           "type":"image\/jpg",
           "url":"http:\/\/a1.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1611029053\/iphone-4-icon_normal.png",
           "width":"48"
        },
        "google:image_link":"http:\/\/a1.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1611029053\/iphone-4-icon_normal.png",
        "twitter:metadata":{
           "twitter:result_type":"recent"
        },
        "y:published":{
           "hour":"11",
           "timezone":"UTC",
           "second":"25",
           "month":"10",
           "month_name":"October",
           "minute":"56",
           "utime":"1319889385",
           "day":"29",
           "day_ordinal_suffix":"th",
           "day_of_week":"6",
           "day_name":"Saturday",
           "year":"2011"
        },
        "y:id":{
           "permalink":"false",
           "value":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/talk_design\/statuses\/130251640623214592"
        },
        "y:title":"talk_design: Pretty cool interactive music video for Ellie Goulding's Lights! #webgl http:\/\/t.co\/kkA3ON09",
        "title":"We Said: Pretty cool interactive music video for Ellie Goulding's Lights! #webgl http:\/\/t.co\/kkA3ON09"
     },
     {
        "link":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/OwenMelbz\/statuses\/129989645940428800",
        "description":"OwenMelbz: @<em>talk_design<\/em> #<em>talk_design<\/em> test test test",
        "pubDate":"Fri, 28 Oct 2011 18:35:21 +0000",
        "guid":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/OwenMelbz\/statuses\/129989645940428800",
        "author":"OwenMelbz@twitter.com (Owen Melbourne)",
        "media:content":{
           "height":"48",
           "type":"image\/jpg",
           "url":"http:\/\/a1.twimg.com\/profile_images\/702379978\/DSC01872222_normal.jpg",
           "width":"48"
        },
        "google:image_link":"http:\/\/a1.twimg.com\/profile_images\/702379978\/DSC01872222_normal.jpg",
        "twitter:metadata":{
           "twitter:result_type":"recent"
        },
        "y:published":{
           "hour":"18",
           "timezone":"UTC",
           "second":"21",
           "month":"10",
           "month_name":"October",
           "minute":"35",
           "utime":"1319826921",
           "day":"28",
           "day_ordinal_suffix":"th",
           "day_of_week":"5",
           "day_name":"Friday",
           "year":"2011"
        },
        "y:id":{
           "permalink":"false",
           "value":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/OwenMelbz\/statuses\/129989645940428800"
        },
        "y:title":"OwenMelbz: @talk_design #talk_design test test test",
        "title":"OwenMelbz:  #talkdesign test test test"
     },
     {
        "link":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/talk_design\/statuses\/129988795574657024",
        "description":"talk_design: Video: Jay Bradner: Open-source cancer researchFrom: TEDtalksDirector | Oct 27, 2011 | 7,265... <a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http:\/\/t.co\/5hrxfCHC\">http:\/\/t.co\/5hrxfCHC<\/a>",
        "pubDate":"Fri, 28 Oct 2011 18:31:58 +0000",
        "guid":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/talk_design\/statuses\/129988795574657024",
        "author":"talk_design@twitter.com (Talk.Design)",
        "media:content":{
           "height":"48",
           "type":"image\/jpg",
           "url":"http:\/\/a1.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1611029053\/iphone-4-icon_normal.png",
           "width":"48"
        },
        "google:image_link":"http:\/\/a1.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1611029053\/iphone-4-icon_normal.png",
        "twitter:metadata":{
           "twitter:result_type":"recent"
        },
        "y:published":{
           "hour":"18",
           "timezone":"UTC",
           "second":"58",
           "month":"10",
           "month_name":"October",
           "minute":"31",
           "utime":"1319826718",
           "day":"28",
           "day_ordinal_suffix":"th",
           "day_of_week":"5",
           "day_name":"Friday",
           "year":"2011"
        },
        "y:id":{
           "permalink":"false",
           "value":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/talk_design\/statuses\/129988795574657024"
        },
        "y:title":"talk_design: Video: Jay Bradner: Open-source cancer researchFrom: TEDtalksDirector | Oct 27, 2011 | 7,265... http:\/\/t.co\/5hrxfCHC",
        "title":"We Said: Video: Jay Bradner: Open-source cancer researchFrom: TEDtalksDirector | Oct 27, 2011 | 7,265... http:\/\/t.co\/5hrxfCHC"
     },
     {
        "link":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/talk_design\/statuses\/129986263011950592",
        "description":"talk_design: setting up website and facebook :)",
        "pubDate":"Fri, 28 Oct 2011 18:21:54 +0000",
        "guid":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/talk_design\/statuses\/129986263011950592",
        "author":"talk_design@twitter.com (Talk.Design)",
        "media:content":{
           "height":"48",
           "type":"image\/jpg",
           "url":"http:\/\/a1.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1611029053\/iphone-4-icon_normal.png",
           "width":"48"
        },
        "google:image_link":"http:\/\/a1.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1611029053\/iphone-4-icon_normal.png",
        "twitter:metadata":{
           "twitter:result_type":"recent"
        },
        "y:published":{
           "hour":"18",
           "timezone":"UTC",
           "second":"54",
           "month":"10",
           "month_name":"October",
           "minute":"21",
           "utime":"1319826114",
           "day":"28",
           "day_ordinal_suffix":"th",
           "day_of_week":"5",
           "day_name":"Friday",
           "year":"2011"
        },
        "y:id":{
           "permalink":"false",
           "value":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/talk_design\/statuses\/129986263011950592"
        },
        "y:title":"talk_design: setting up website and facebook :)",
        "title":"We Said: setting up website and facebook :)"
     }
  ]
}
}
```

however for the life of me I cant construct my string that I want. the "theory" I'm using is.

```
while i <= json[count]{ //open loop using json count data
    tweet = json[items[i]][description]; //get the tweet
    tweet = tweet.replace(/\/g,""); //remove slashes
    by = json[items[i]][author]; //get author
    by = by.split("("); //ignore full name just get short
    by = by[1]; // shortname
    by = by.replace(/)/g,""); //remove last )
    avatar = json[items[i]][media:content][url]; //get avatar url
    avatar = avatar.replace(/\/g, "") //remove slashes
    tweet = "<img src=""+avatar+"" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" />"+author+": "+tweet; //format the tweet
    $("#tweetarea").append(tweet); //print it to #tweetarea
    i++ //update counter
} //close loop
```

but honestly i cant figure out this json lark. would anybody be willing to write the jquery code to parse this json. and perform the actions i described above?

thank you :)

Comment: try to organize your question in precise and neat format that would help you get your answer sir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to easily iterate over the JSON and append specific tweet data to `#tweetarea`:

```
$.each(json.value.items, function(i, tweet) {
        var author = tweet.author.split('(')[1].replace(')','');
        var avatar = tweet['media:content'].url;
        $('#tweetarea').append('<img src="'+avatar+'" width="16" height="16" />'+author+': '+tweet['y:title']+'<br/>');
});
```

See a [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/934Mj/)

Edit:

You can load the JSON via jQuery's [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method. Here is an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/934Mj/4/).

Comment: ah this is brilliant thanks, how do i go about loading the feed into var json however?

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery AJAX API w/ settings for JSONP. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yahoourlhere?callback=?'
    dataType: 'jsonp',
}).success(function(response, status, jqxhr) {

}).error(function(jqxhr, status, error) {

});
```

You'll need to see if you can get the name of the callback wrapped around the PIPEs feed. This is a PHP example of how you would wrap JSON for a JSONP call:

```
<?php
    $callback = $_REQUEST['callback'];
    echo "$callback\($json\)";
?>
```